# Problems pushing large commit using JGit

Tags: java, git, push, jgit

I have a Java application that syncs two Git repositories. This works fine 90% of the time, but when a lot of changes happen, my program just commits and doesn't push. I am using `Runtime.exec` to create the commit (because I had problems with whitespaces using JGit and this is just a quick and dirty tool).

```java
git.push().setRemote( remote ).add( branch ).setCredentialsProvider( loginProvider ).call();
```

Doesn't push the commit, but doesn't throw an Exception either.
I currently manually push the branch if the program freezes and that works fine.
I'm new to JGit so this might be a simple fix, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: call() returns a data structure, how does it look like?

Comment: @Rüdiger Hermann I don't know, when this occurs I can't analyze anything, because my program freezes. I think that jGit somehow just stops working but doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: If it causing you major problem, Use http://www.perforce.com

Comment: How do you know it is the push call that freezes your program?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann yes I do, Everything to that point executes just fine and the next line is fully ignored. I tried it in a small test class to make sure that I have no other errors. And as I said this problem only occures when there are a lot of changes to the repository. I run this in a look over 20 ish repositories at a time and have no problem whatsoever if a few files change in each

Comment: My guess is that there is an authentication problem. Can you edit your question to include details as to which authentication method the remote repository uses and how the `loginProvider` looks like? Also note, that some repositories may have a file size restriction. In such case, however, a corresponding result should be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't a authentication problem occur with every push? I don't have problems with the login provider. It works fine for cloning and pulling and like I said for almost every push. The repository also accepts large commits and my git is configured to send those, since I can push these commits from command line and from source tree. I thought there might be a simple fix, but if that isn't the case it's probably not worth the time to fix at all

Comment: You are right. This may as well be a bug in JGit. If you can provide a repository to reproduce the problem, please follow this link to file a bug: https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/support/

Comment: No I can't since this is a problem that I encountered at work. I also haven't figured out how large the commit has to be. I have resorted to just check the commit size and not push after a certain point. I still apreciate the help tho